# Android: Change color of all buttons in listview when a button pressed

Tags: java, android, listview

In a listview, on each row, I have 10 buttons. When any of those buttons pressed, color of the buttons should changed (its like filling the bar based on where you pressed) . 
Here is what I've done so far:
I have added references of each button to an ArrayList called buttons.
Also, I have an ArrayList which has colors strings.
This is click listener that is assigned to each button.

This is complete  code form my adapter class of the listview.

```
public class TeacherRatingAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<Votes> {

    private ArrayList<String> colors = new ArrayList();

    private ArrayList<Button> buttons = new ArrayList<>();
    private LayoutInflater inflater;
    private ArrayList<Votes> mItems = new ArrayList<>();
    private ArrayList<Votes> mItemsTemp = new ArrayList<>();
    private int teacher;
    private boolean myTeacher;
    private ArrayList<Pair<Integer, Integer>> questionHint = new ArrayList<>();
    private static int givenMark;
    private HashMap<String, Integer> givenMarks = new HashMap<>();
    ViewHolder viewHolder;

    public TeacherRatingAdapter(Context context, TeacherRating teacherRating) {
        super(context, -1, teacherRating.getVotes());
        mItems = teacherRating.getVotes();
        if(mItems.size()==0){
            for(int i = 0; i<10; i++){
                mItems.add(new Votes());
            }
        }
        for(int i = 0; i<teacherRating.getVotes().size(); i++){
            givenMarks.put(String.valueOf(i+1), teacherRating.getVotes().get(i).getAll().get(i));
        }
        teacher = teacherRating.getTeacher();
        myTeacher = teacherRating.isMy_teacher();

        questionHint.add(new Pair<>(R.string.question1, R.string.questionHint1));
        questionHint.add(new Pair<>(R.string.question2, R.string.questionHint2));
        questionHint.add(new Pair<>(R.string.question3, R.string.questionHint3));
        questionHint.add(new Pair<>(R.string.question4, R.string.questionHint4));
        questionHint.add(new Pair<>(R.string.question5, R.string.questionHint5));
        questionHint.add(new Pair<>(R.string.question6, R.string.questionHint6));
        questionHint.add(new Pair<>(R.string.question7, R.string.questionHint7));
        questionHint.add(new Pair<>(R.string.question8, R.string.questionHint8));
        questionHint.add(new Pair<>(R.string.question9, R.string.questionHint9));
        questionHint.add(new Pair<>(R.string.question10, R.string.questionHint10));

        colors.add("#E77272");
        colors.add("#E77D72");
        colors.add("#E78D72");
        colors.add("#E7A472");
        colors.add("#E8B472");
        colors.add("#E8C272");
        colors.add("#E8C272");
        colors.add("#E6E773");
        colors.add("#c3e874");
        colors.add("#89e874");
    }

    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        return mItems.size() > 0 ? mItems.size() : 1;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean isEnabled(int position) {
        return mItems.size() != 0;
    }

    View.OnClickListener clickListener = new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            Button button = (Button) v;
            String text = button.getText().toString();
            if(text.equals("1")){
                givenMark = 1;
            }else if(text.equals("2")){
                givenMark = 2;
            }else if(text.equals("3")){
                givenMark = 3;
            }else if(text.equals("4")){
                givenMark = 4;
            }else if(text.equals("5")){
                givenMark = 5;
            }else if(text.equals("6")){
                givenMark = 6;
            }else if(text.equals("7")){
                givenMark = 7;
            }else if(text.equals("8")){
                givenMark = 8;
            }else if(text.equals("9")){
                givenMark = 9;
            }else if(text.equals("10")){
                givenMark = 10;
            }

            colorButton(givenMark, viewHolder);
//            button.setBackgroundColor(Color.parseColor(colors.get(givenMark)));
            mItems.get(Integer.valueOf(button.getTag().toString())).addOne(Integer.valueOf(text));
//            mItems.get(Integer.valueOf(button.getTag().toString())).setScore(Integer.valueOf(text), givenMark);
//            givenMarks.put(button.getTag().toString(), givenMark);
            notifyDataSetChanged();
        }
    };

    @Override
    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        inflater = LayoutInflater.from(getContext());
        if (mItems.size() == 0) {
            if (!Common.isNetworkConnected(getContext())) {
                convertView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.list_item_no_internet, null, false);
            } else {
                convertView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.list_item_no_content, null, false);
            }
            return convertView;
        } else {
            if (convertView == null) {
                buttons.clear();
                convertView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.list_item_teacher_rating, parent, false);
                viewHolder = new ViewHolder();
                viewHolder.mQuestionTextView = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.question);
                viewHolder.mHintTextView = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.question_hint);
                viewHolder.button1 = (Button) convertView.findViewById(R.id.question_button_1);
                viewHolder.button2 = (Button) convertView.findViewById(R.id.question_button_2);
                viewHolder.button3 = (Button) convertView.findViewById(R.id.question_button_3);
                viewHolder.button4 = (Button) convertView.findViewById(R.id.question_button_4);
                viewHolder.button5 = (Button) convertView.findViewById(R.id.question_button_5);
                viewHolder.button6 = (Button) convertView.findViewById(R.id.question_button_6);
                viewHolder.button7 = (Button) convertView.findViewById(R.id.question_button_7);
                viewHolder.button8 = (Button) convertView.findViewById(R.id.question_button_8);
                viewHolder.button9 = (Button) convertView.findViewById(R.id.question_button_9);
                viewHolder.button10 = (Button) convertView.findViewById(R.id.question_button_10);

                viewHolder.button1.setOnClickListener(clickListener);
                viewHolder.button2.setOnClickListener(clickListener);
                viewHolder.button3.setOnClickListener(clickListener);
                viewHolder.button4.setOnClickListener(clickListener);
                viewHolder.button5.setOnClickListener(clickListener);
                viewHolder.button6.setOnClickListener(clickListener);
                viewHolder.button7.setOnClickListener(clickListener);
                viewHolder.button8.setOnClickListener(clickListener);
                viewHolder.button9.setOnClickListener(clickListener);
                viewHolder.button1.setOnClickListener(clickListener);

                viewHolder.button1.setTag(position);
                viewHolder.button2.setTag(position);
                viewHolder.button3.setTag(position);
                viewHolder.button4.setTag(position);
                viewHolder.button5.setTag(position);
                viewHolder.button6.setTag(position);
                viewHolder.button7.setTag(position);
                viewHolder.button8.setTag(position);
                viewHolder.button9.setTag(position);
                viewHolder.button1.setTag(position);

                buttons.add(viewHolder.button1);
                buttons.add(viewHolder.button2);
                buttons.add(viewHolder.button3);
                buttons.add(viewHolder.button4);
                buttons.add(viewHolder.button5);
                buttons.add(viewHolder.button6);
                buttons.add(viewHolder.button7);
                buttons.add(viewHolder.button8);
                buttons.add(viewHolder.button9);
                buttons.add(viewHolder.button10);

                convertView.setTag(viewHolder);
            } else {
                viewHolder = (ViewHolder) convertView.getTag();
            }
            viewHolder.mQuestionTextView.setText(questionHint.get(position).getValue0());
            viewHolder.mHintTextView.setText(questionHint.get(position).getValue1());
            Votes item = getItem(position);

            int count = 0;
            double score = 0;
            for(int i = 0; i<item.getAll().size(); i++){
                score += (i+1) * item.getAll().get(i);
                count +=item.getAll().get(i);
            }
            if(count>0){
                score = score/count;
            }
            if(score==0){
                score = 10;
            }
//            double diff = (10-Math.round(score));
            colorButton(Math.round(score), viewHolder);
//            colorButton((int) score);
//            for (int j = 9; j >= diff; j--) {
//                Button button = buttons.get(j);
//                button.setBackgroundColor(Color.WHITE);
//                button.setTextColor(Color.BLACK);
//            }
        }
        return convertView;
    }

    private void colorButton(long givenMark, ViewHolder viewHolder){
        for(int i=0; i<buttons.size();i++){
            buttons.get(i).setBackgroundColor(Color.WHITE);
        }
        for (int j = 0; j <= givenMark; j++) {
            Button button = buttons.get(j);
            button.setBackgroundColor(Color.parseColor(colors.get(j)));
        }
    }

    private static class ViewHolder {
        TextView mQuestionTextView;
        TextView mHintTextView;
        Button button1;
        Button button2;
        Button button3;
        Button button4;
        Button button5;
        Button button6;
        Button button7;
        Button button8;
        Button button9;
        Button button10;
    }
}
```

It looks like this:
[image]
So, when I press button 3, all colors beyond 3, must become white. Or when I press button 9, all buttons before it must have its colors, and buttons in fron of it must be white. But this does not happen, and there is no error. 
Thank you for any help.

Comment: Can you do it with 10 simple button inside horizontal scrollview. If your view is fixed only

Comment: in your code what is problem ??

Comment: is there any error coming ??

Comment: No, no error. Actually. when inside my click listener I make code to only change the color of the pressed butto, it works, but like this, it does not.

Comment: can u share your complete code?

Answer (score 0):

Isn't that rating bar?

OnClickListener is wrong, I meant not the right listener, you got the idea wrong. What's the enclosing View?

Comment: Yes, I want to make a rating bar. Not sure what you mean by enclosure view. But these are 10 Buttons that located on a litsview item. I use ListFragment.